# Dimension of the set of forms of degree $d$ in the homogeneous coordinate ring of $V$ (Fulton, Exercise 4.10)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

I need help to solve the following problem that appears on page 55 of the book of William Fulton entitled *Algebraic Curves*.

**Exercise** :

Let $ R = k[X,Y,Z] $, $F \in R$ an irreducible form of degree $n$, $ V=V( F ) \subset \mathbb{P}^2 $, and $ \Gamma = \Gamma_h (V) = k[X,Y,Z] / I(V) $ the homogeneous coordinate ring of $V$.

1) Construct an exact sequence $ \ 0 \to R\stackrel{\psi} \to R \stackrel{\varphi} \to \Gamma \to 0 $, where $ \psi $ is the multiplication by $F$.

2) Show that $ \mathrm{dim}_k \ \{ \text{forms of degree} \ d \ \ \text{in} \ \Gamma   \} = dn - \dfrac{n(n-3)}{2} $ if $ d > n $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Were you able to do part 1? Can you see what the connection is with part 2?

Comment: About part 1), $ \psi $ is defined by : $ \psi ( P ) = FP $. and $ \varphi $ is défined by : $ \varphi ( Q ) = \overline{Q} = Q + I(V) $. So, $ \forall P \in R $ : $ \varphi \circ \psi ( P ) = \varphi ( FP ) = FP + I(V) = 0 $, because : $ FP \in I(V) $, no ? So, $ \mathrm{Im} \ \psi \subset \mathrm{ker} \varphi $, no ? Or, equivalently. $ \psi $ is injective ( It's clear ), and, $ \varphi $ is th canonical surjection, so it's surjective, no ? So, the sequence is exact, no ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: OK, good. And what about the degree-d forms in $\Gamma$? Can you use what you just did to calculate that dimension?

Comment: I don't know. :-p Sorry. It's so hard.

Comment: Under $\phi$, what happens to forms of degree $d$?

Comment: forms of degree $d$ vanish under $ \varphi $ i think.

Comment: No matter what $d$ is? That's a lot of forms to vanish! :)

Comment: Bryan, you should use the exact sequence  of finite-dimensional vector spaces $  0 \to R_{d-n} \stackrel { \times F}{ \to} R_d \to \Gamma_d \to 0 $, where the indices denote homogeneous component of the stated degree. You then use that the dimension of the middle vector space is the sum of the dimensions of the other two vector spaces. By the way, I upvoted your question,  in order  to cancel an unfair downvote to your perfectly reasonable and legitimate question.

Comment: Thank you. So : $ \mathrm{dim}_k \ \{ \text{forms of degree} \ d $ $ \ \mathrm{in} \ \Gamma_{d}  \ \} = \mathrm{dim}_k \Gamma_d = \mathrm{dim}_k R_d - \mathrm{dim}_k R_{d - n } $, no ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the right formula. And good luck for your further study of algebraic geometry: do not hesitate to post new questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you. So, since : $ \mathrm{dim}_k R_d = \dfrac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2} $ and $ \mathrm{dim}_k R_{d-n} = \dfrac{(d-n+1)(d-n+2)}{2} $, then : $ \mathrm{dim}_k \Gamma_k = \dfrac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2} - \dfrac{(d-n+1)(d-n+2)}{2}  = dn - \dfrac{n(n-3)}{2} $, no ?  :)